# iOS library for world map UI like Ocarina or UNIQLO Wake Up

Tags: ios, user-interface, dictionary, 3d, visualization

I wish to implement an iOS app that visualizes the world map in the way Ocarina or UNIQLO Wake Up does. Is there any library for doing this or do I have to implement it from scratch? Any pointers to implementation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think they have used a custom map using [MapBox](http://mapbox.com/?ev=0&utm_expid=62793361-4). Using MapBox we can create maps also we can use source from Open Street Map.

Comment: +1 for a useful pointer. I have to check whether this library supports visualization of 3d globe.

Comment: what is the mobile support on this one ? I see only iOS in the info

Answer (score 1):

MapBox does not support visualization for a truly 3D globe, though you could potentially script that yourself.  An example of how you can use MapBox to make a 3D map can be found [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-earth). However, a good starter point for 3D visualization like that might be [this](https://github.com/RossAnderson/EarthView) sample project on GitHub.